# How to change default icon of a ContextualMenu

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, react-tsx, office-ui-fabric-react

Referring to examples of ContextualMenu in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/contextualmenu, I want to change the default icon (ChevronDown) to ChevronUp. How do I do that?
I tried a few options by providing a styles variable with desired icon and no success yet.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `menuIconProps` prop of the office ui fabric Button component to change the icon.

```
<Button menuIconProps={{ iconName:"MoreVertical" }} menuProps={{ items:[]}}>
   Click Me
</Button>
```